# LEFT JOIN takes too long when SORTING results with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, left-join

this is my first question in stackoverflow, usually I'm used to searching the internet for an answer, but this time i could not find any answer for this question.

Simply my problem is a query takes TOO long to execute while it's a simple join between 2 tables

I'll post my query first then i will post more details about my system:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_item 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM tbl_item_details) AS tbl_item_details 
ON tbl_item.item_id = tbl_item_details.item_details_item_id 
WHERE item_active = 1 ORDER BY item_views DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

Here is my tables structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_item` (
`item_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`item_views` int(11) NOT NULL,
`item_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=821 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

tbl_item_details:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_item_details` (
`item_details_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`item_details_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`item_details_content` longtext NOT NULL,
`item_details_item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`item_details_id`),
KEY `itm_dt_itm_id` (`item_details_item_id`),
CONSTRAINT `tbl_item_details_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`itm_dt_itm_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_item` (`itm_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=364 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

here is EXPLAIN query output:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     tbl_item    ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    358     Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY       ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    358      
2   DERIVED     tbl_item_details    ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    422
```

each tables has ONLY 350 rows, and the big table (tbl_item_details) 1.5 MB so you see the tables are pretty small.

BASICALLY, the above query takes almost 4 seconds to execute on the following system:

CPU: Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.20GHz (2 CPUs), ~3.2GHz
RAM: 3 GB
Mysql: 5.1.33 (included with wamp)

BEFORE, anyone suggests a solution here is what I tried, what worked and what did not:

things that worked  and the query took much less time (0.06 seconds):

- I tried removing ORDER BY I tried removing item_details_content from
- the select I tried using INNER JOIN instead and it worked I tried
- switching the tables in the join so the INNER table became OUTER and vice versa

I CANNOT use INNER JOIN because there might be rows in tbl_item that does not have matches in tbl_item_details and i want these records

things i tried which DID NOT work:

- I tried adding an index to item_views (DID NOT WORK)
- I tried removing the foreign keys constraints
- I tried witching the tables engine to MyIsam

Obviously the problem happens when mysql is sorting the date and faces (relatively) large data in item_details_content, so if we get rid of one of the things (either sorting or the column item_details_content) it works just fine.

but the thing is, this should not happen! cos the table has really very small data considering it's just 350 rows with total of 1.5 MB! mysql should be able to handle much more data than that.

PLEASE, before suggesting drastic changes to the query structure, I'm afraid that is not possible, because I've been working on this framework for a while and the query is dynamically generated, and changes to the query might mean days of work BUT your suggestions are always welcome.

P.S: I tried this query on a powerful server (core i7 and 8 GB RAM) and it took 0.3 seconds which is still too long for such a database

Thanks a million

Comment: Sorry, gotta go but a quick hint: I think the problem is that you are not doing "a simple join", because you join on a subquery. The resultset of that query does NOT have indexes, as it is created on the fly. Only joins on tables (that have indexes!) are quick. Do your join on `tbl_item_details` instead of on a `SELECT` of that table.

Comment: Consider adding an index to column tbl_items.item_views. That should improve the query performance.

Comment: Nanne, thanks for the answer, but how about conditions on the joined table, actually that table is supposed to have 2 or more rows for each row in the first table (a row for each language). so would it be safe to go like ON tbl_item.item_id = tbl_item_details.item_details_item_id and tbl_item_details.item_language = VALUE ??

Comment: bfavaretto, it sure did not as i mentioned earlier in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_item 
LEFT JOIN tbl_item_details 
ON tbl_item.item_id = tbl_item_details.item_details_item_id 
WHERE item_active = 1 ORDER BY item_views DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

I really don't think you need the nested subquery that just selects * from tbl_item_details -- just use the table.

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly mean when u say indexing, are you talking about the field I'm sorting by! cos yes I've tried an index on that and it does not change anything, or if you mean i do not have indexes in the second table then yea, it has an index and it has a primary key as well (I'm not assuming you mean i should add fulltext index) on the item_details_content field

Comment: Ah, I just meant adding an index, but I have forgotten that declaring a field as a primary key implicitly indexes the field, so nevermind on the indexing. Did eliminating the subquery help?

Comment: @Al-Kateb one last thing... if your application does NOT have a lot of concurrent users that are updating different rows in the tables at the same time, then maybe you should try MyISAM for the engine instead of InnoDB. There's a little note here about the differences, but from what I understand InnoDB uses row locking vs table locking, and is also less efficient with the CPU. 

http://www.mikebernat.com/blog/MySQL_-_InnoDB_vs_MyISAM

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I depend too much on the foreign keys constraints, but eliminating the sub queries definitely helped, I'm building a framkework in PHP, so when i first decided to join on sub queries i was thinking of having where conditions inside the sub query and i did not know it would cause too much impact on the performance, so I'm just gonna remove it and join on tables instead cos it's just not worth it. Thanks a lot guys for the answer

Comment: Ah yeah, fk constraints kinda tank the myisam idea. Perhaps you could have a stored procedure that inserts data into a temp table so you don't need a subquery (not sure if that even makes sense for your data). I am actually somewhat surprised it affected the query so badly -- I've used subqueries with joins before, only I usually use them in the where clause instead of the join part so that could be why. Anyawy, best of luck to you.